# Extract only Date from $$.Execution.StartTime in stepfunctions statemachine

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge, aws-step-functions

I am writing a step function state machine in aws cloud formation template. The state machine is triggered from EventBridge Rule with a scheduled expression.

One of the state task needs S3 path as parameter which has todays date in the path. To get the date, i am using $$.Execution.StartTime. However $$.Execution.StartTime is returning string value such as "2022-07-11T14:09:19.196Z"

I would like to extract just the date "2022-07-11" from above string so, i can form another string for my s3 file path which has date in the path (as folder name).

AWS state language doesnt seem to have intrinsic functions for string split. Also, i dont find a way to use Fn::Split cloud formation intrinsic function inside sate machine definition string.

I would like to achieve this without using lambda function to split the datetime.

Any inputs or techniques appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SF which formates the $$.Execution.StartTime and formats as `YYYYDDMM` and return it.

```
{
  "StartAt": "SplitDate",
  "States": {
    "SplitDate": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "YYYY.$": "States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit(States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.Execution.StartTime, 'T'), 0), '-'), 0)",
        "MM.$": "States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit(States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.Execution.StartTime, 'T'),0), '-'), 1)",
        "DD.$": "States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit(States.ArrayGetItem(States.StringSplit($$.Execution.StartTime, 'T'),0), '-'), 2)"
      },
      "Next": "ReturnYYYYMMDD"
    },
    "ReturnYYYYMMDD": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "Date.$": "States.Format('{}{}{}',$.YYYY,$.MM, $.DD)"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```